# Extra custom parameters in Form Authentication on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, forms-authentication

I had developed a form based authentication which has `j_username` and `j_password` and action as `j_security_check`. Now I need **another (third) input field** (select field) getting the authentication type where the user will be directed to different pages based on the third input field. How do I access the selected third input field to continue the process. I just came to know that I had to use **Form Authenticator Java  Class** and **extend it** to get the select input field, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
<form id="book-form" method="post" action="j_security_check" >
    <div>
       User Name 
        <input type="text" name="j_username" id="title" class="u-full-width" placeholder="Enter username" required>
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="j_password" id="isbn" class="u-full-width" placeholder="Enter password" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <select name="choice" id="type-list" class="u-full-width" required>
        <option value="one">Tomcat Local User</option>
        <option value="two">Computer Domain User</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </div>
</form>
```